# How to detect when a string has a common business suffix (e.g. "Inc.", "LLC', "GmbH")

Tags: ruby, rubygems, string-matching, names

I would like to find a library (Ruby gem) to detect when a string contains the common suffixes used in business names (e.g. Inc, LLC, LLP, GmbH, PC, etc). My goal is to detect when we have a business name versus a human name; specifically, we don't want to treat a business name "Company, Inc" the same as human name "Last, First", e.g. we don't want to reverse a business name to "Inc Company".

I found a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_companies) that seems to document the various types of companies but I haven't found any gems or just a simple list.

First choice would be finding a gem, second would be a set of regex strings, and last just a list of suffixes.

Comment: There might be a gem for this. However, it is quite normal to handle companies as a data modelling and UX issue, as opposed to auto-detect them based on contents of a "full_name" field. Simplest form of this is probably to have an optional field "company_name" on User model. Also, doing even apparently simple things such as "Last, First" to name fields probably breaks a lot with human names anyway. Names are one of those pieces of data that just get more and more complex the closer you look . . . usually the best option is to not look inside the string, just display as-is.

Comment: +1 @NeilSlater. Names are names, and you can't parse them to determine first/last or whether they're entities like businesses. If you need to differentiate, then give the user separate fields for their first, last and business and don't try to second-guess them. Second-guessing always fails badly eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but we are not in control of how this data is created. It comes from multiple sources with very little control or marshaling. This is partly because this field represents an entity that can be either a real person or a fictitious entity. Thus we have no choice but to parse and try to deduce the type of entity it is.

Answer (score 0):

The "consistent_company" gem has a "IsCompanyWord" Function that recognizes specific words as commonly-used in company names.

You can check it out [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/consistent_company)!

Hope this helps!